# How to write a custom time ProgressBar with preset time?

Tags: java, android, progress-bar, runnable

I want to write a piece of code that foresaw a `ProgressBar` for 30 seconds.

For example, we have a timer that allows the user to decide whether to press this button for 30 seconds , In the meantime, we want the user to **display a status bar for 30 seconds**

Do I do this with a `Runnable` or `For loop`?

Comment: can you post your code @Majid

Comment: The answers are examples of code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this class and my problem was solved

```
public class RequestActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ProgressBar progress_bar;
    private TextView    progress_count;
    private int         REQUEST_TIMER  = 0;
    private Timer       timer          = new Timer(); 
    private Handler     handler        = new Handler();
    private int         counter        = 0; 
    private timerTask   task           = new timerTask();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_travel_request);
        progress_bar   = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);
        progress_count = (TextView)    findViewById(R.id.progress_count);
        REQUEST_TIMER  = getIntent().getIntExtra("timeout", 0);
        progress_bar.setMax(REQUEST_TIMER);
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, 500, 1000);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        task.cancel();
    }

    private class timerTask extends TimerTask {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    counter++;
                    progress_count.setText(
                        String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%d", counter));
                    progress_bar.setProgress(counter);
                    if (counter >= REQUEST_TIMER) {
                        TravelRequestActivity.this.finish();
                        Toast.makeText(
                            getApplicationContext(), "STOP", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for displaying a progress for 30 seconds you can do something like this

in your activity/fragment

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements TimerTask{

    Timer timer;
    ProgressDialog progressBar;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);
        timer = new Timer();
        progressBar = new ProgressDialog(this);  
        progressBar.setCancelable(true);//you can cancel it by pressing back button  
        progressBar.setMessage("Something downloading ...");  
        progressBar.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);  
        progressBar.setProgress(0); 
        progressBar.setMax(100);
        progressBar.show(); 
        timer.schedule(this,2000);
     }

 @Override
    public void run() {
        //here dismiss the progress dialog
        progressBar.dismiss();
    }

 }
```

Comment: I use the horizontal type ProgressBar, please do not help with the Dialog ProgressBar.

`ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);`

`<ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
private void setProgressDialogAnimation(ProgressBar mProgressBar, int process) {
    ObjectAnimator animation = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(mProgressBar, "progress", 0, process);
    animation.setDuration(30000);//30 second
    animation.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
    animation.start();
}
```